# The possibilities of what someone meant

Tags: sentence-construction

Imagine person A and person B are talking to each other.A tells B about what person C said to A. A uses the same sentences what C said but A could not understand what C meant exactly.Now B knows what C said to A. B have some  idea or guess what C meant but B is not sure either.So B makes some guesses based on what C said.

I'd like to ask how B should start his sentence when he makes guess about what C meant?

B says to A:

1.C could mean...

2.C could have meant...

3.C may/might mean...

4.C may/might have meant...

5.C would have meant...

Comment: Either 2 or an adapted 4:C may/might have **meant** ..

Comment: @StoneyB do you think if there is a difference between them  and I have also added another option

Comment: The forms without the 'perfect' past marker imply that C still 'means' whatever it is. 5 implies certainty - it's equivalent to *must have meant*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**C could mean...** is present tense, but B is referring to something that happened in the past.

**C could have meant...** is a valid option for what B is trying to convey.  The use of the word "could" indicates possibility and capability, as well as some uncertainty on B's part.

**C may/might mean...** is present tense again.

**C may/might have meant...** is a valid option for what B is trying to convey.  The use of the words "may" or "might" indicates possibility, as well as greater uncertainty on B's part.

**C would have meant...** would indicate certainty on B's part as to what C meant, as mentioned in StoneyB's comment.

For more information on word choice with could/may/might, you may wish to refer to these posts:
[“Might have” vs “could have”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64374/might-have-vs-could-have)
[“It could/might/may be funny” — what is the correct usage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/it-could-might-may-be-funny-what-is-the-correct-usage)

Answer (score 1):

B is not sure and he guesses/assumes. He can say..."C could have meant.."
According to the level of possibility, we can change the modal verb.
For less possibility - might. For much possibility - could. It is up to B's guess/assumption.